# python-qgis version information

Tags: python, version, qgis

Can someone tell me how I get the version information for [python-qgis](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html)?

I have tried all the usual `foo.version` or `foo.__version__` or `foo.VERSION`.  If someone knows how to do this, it would be a great help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
As of QGIS 3+, this is now in `qgis.core.Qgis.QGIS_VERSION`

**Original answer:**

You can use [`qgis.utils.QGis.QGIS_VERSION`](http://qgis.org/api/classQGis.html#a6b0157f79c7ebd7ab16f6ffd21a24b79):

```
>>> import qgis.utils
>>> qgis.utils.QGis.QGIS_VERSION
'2.0.1-Dufour'
```

Comment: Brilliant!  I have been digging around for ages trying to find an answer to this.  I never thought it would be buried that deep in the package. +1

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS3, this has changed to (`Qgis` instead of `QGis`)

```
>>> import qgis.utils
>>> qgis.utils.Qgis.QGIS_VERSION
'3.1.0-Master'
```

A way to figure out whether the version is >=3.0 or not seems to be

(QGIS >=3.0)

```
>>> import qgis.utils
>>> hasattr(qgis.utils, 'Qgis')
True
```

(QGIS <= 2.18)

```
>>> import qgis.utils
>>> hasattr(qgis.utils, 'Qgis')
False
```

Comment: In QGIS 3 we can also find the version in: qgis.core.Qgis.QGIS_VERSION