# exceptions/traceback not showing after importing qgis-utils

Tags: python, exception, qgis, traceback

Following on from a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239144/python-qgis-version-information) I asked about getting the version information from `python-qgis`, with a brilliant solution provided by @falsetru, I am running into a problem whereby importing `qgis.utils` seems to hide all exceptions.  Running the following code in the interpreter, I get no traceback, or anything useful following a raised exception, see below.

```
>>> import qgis.utils
>>> qgis.utils.QGis.QGIS_VERSION
'2.4.0-Chugiak'
>>> raise Exception('boof!')
>>>
```

Could someone tell me how I can turn back on traceback after importing `qgis-utils` or another way of getting the version information from `python-qgis` without needing to import `utils`?

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you try `traceback` module? if not import traceback and use functions like `traceback.print_exc` or ... .

Comment: I don't have much experience with the `traceback` module I'm afraid.  I tried running `traceback.print_exc()` as you suggested, but with no success.  I will read up on that module.  I have also noticed the warnings module.  Could it also be related to this?

Comment: Possibly yes. maybe the module you imported filtered warnings use `warnings` module.

Comment: It looks like I can use `qgis.core.QGis.QGIS_VERSION` to get the version info, so I didn't need to use `utils` after all.  It is however, still a problem, and one I will continue to look into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, which allows me to avoid using the `utils` module to get the version information, and uses the `core` module instead.

```
>>> import qgis.core
>>> qgis.core.Qgis.QGIS_VERSION
'2.4.0-Chugiak'
>>> raise Exception('boof!')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception: boof!
```

This doesn't provide a full answer to my question, but does provide a work-around to get the version information for `python-qgis`.